# Create new object from constructor in C#

Tags: c#, constructor

I'm new at C#. I'm trying to create an new object from another class' constructor.

```
namespace ClientsCatalgoWindowsForms
{
    public partial class GeneralForm : Form
    {
        public GeneralForm(string ClientName)
        {
            string FormName = ClientName;

           // Client CurrClient = new Client(FormName);
            Client CurrClient = new Client();
            InitializeComponent();


        //ClientForm(ClientName);
        }

        private void OkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //CreateBatch(true);



            CreateObjectsArray();

            CreateControlArray(false);

            //CreateBatch(0);

            Application.Exit();
        }
```

I try to create a new object of type `Client` with name `CurrClient`.

When I try to use it in one of the the class' method, they don't recognize the new object. What am I doing wrong?

The new object class appeares in another cs-file. Does it matter?

Comment: At the moment, you're creating the new object just fine. The problem is, the only reference you have to it is in a *local variable*. You need a field in your class instead (as one solution)

Comment: Please read basics of the language. [Fields (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare currClient variable at class level, and initialize that in constructor. After that you should be able to use currClient in other methods.

```
  namespace ClientsCatalgoWindowsForms
{
    public partial class GeneralForm : Form
    {
        Client CurrClient = null;
        public GeneralForm(string ClientName)
        {
            string FormName = ClientName;

           // Client CurrClient = new Client(FormName);
            CurrClient = new Client();
            InitializeComponent();


        //ClientForm(ClientName);
        }

        private void OkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //CreateBatch(true);



            CreateObjectsArray();

            CreateControlArray(false);

            //CreateBatch(0);

            Application.Exit();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the reference to the object is the *GeneralForm* constructor, try the following, hope it helps.

```
 public partial class GeneralForm : Form
{
    public Client CurrClient;

    public GeneralForm(string ClientName)
    {
        string FormName = ClientName;
        CurrClient = new Client();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A constructor is just a function(Method) that gets called internally when ever a "class" is instantiated.
It contains code that must be executed during the creation of object.
Its main use is to give values to the variables(members) present in the class.

```
      class Sample
{   
  .......
  // Constructor
  public Sample() {}
  .......
}

// an object is created of the  Sample class,
// So above constructor is called
Sample obj = new Sample();
```